# Android button style layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a dashboard with icons and text like in the picture below.
What I want is a round-cornered filled background behind the 'My status' text. I drew on the picture what I want, but it needs to be filled, not only bordered like here (it's just for clarity that I drew it like that on the picture).

[image: What I have and want]

Right now this button is made through a style:

```
 <style name="DashboardButton">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#877871</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
 </style>
```

How can I adapt this style to acheive it?
Can I also set the hover and active states via a style?

Answer (score 0):

For the background to the button's text you either try to do this with a custom background graphic, but I think it would be easier to split your "button" into two parts and render the icon part as an ImageButton and for the label part as a normal button with a custom [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) for the background, e.g. like so:

```
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#0000FF" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners
            android:radius="8dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="8dp"
            android:top="8dp"
            android:right="8dp"
            android:bottom="8dp" />
    </shape>
```

For setting **hover and active states** you can use Android's [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).